# How to remove the dot from a file extension in an array-Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of file extensions:

```
arr = [".png",".jpeg",".pdf",".json"......".jsx"]; // these file extensions are dynamic
```

every file extension has a dot preceeding it and I'm trying to remove that dot so that the o/p becomes:

```
arr=["png","jpeg","pdf","json"......"jsx"]
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you just need to go over each item in the array and modify the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the array into a new array by replacing '.' with '', like so:

```
const arr = [".png",".jpeg",".pdf",".json"];
const newArray = arr.map(x => {
  return x.replace('.','');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `map` function like this:

```
[".png",".jpeg",".pdf",".json",".jsx"].map(e => e.substring(1))
```

This returns:

```
["png", "jpeg", "pdf", "json", "jsx"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using map!

```
myArr = [".png",".jpeg",".pdf",".json",".jsx"];

myArr = myArr.map(item => {
    return item.substring(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a simple loop to iterate through the elements of the array and removing the dot from each file extension. Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
let arr = [".png", ".jpeg", ".pdf", ".json", ".jsx"];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].slice(1);
}

console.log(arr);
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
["png", "jpeg", "pdf", "json", "jsx"]
```